# iteration through Symbol.iterator doesn't happen

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Node.js v10.11.0

Why iteration doesn't happen in my code?

```
'use strict';
const stuff = Object.create(null)
stuff.items = ['a','b','c','d']
stuff[Symbol.iterator] = function*(){
    return this.items[Symbol.iterator]()
}
for(let n of stuff){
    console.log(n) // It doesn't happen
}
```

Comment: You may wanna have a look at the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: @nina what?! Its an iterable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generator function does not `yield` anything, you only return another iterator but the return value is ignored in a for..of. Instead you either yield the entries of the other iterator:

```
 stuff[Symbol.iterator] = function*(){
   yield* this.items[Symbol.iterator]();
 };
```

or you turn the generator function into a regular one (remove the `*`):

```
stuff[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
   return this.items[Symbol.iterator]();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `stuff` iterator to be the `items` iterator:

```js
const stuff = Object.create(null)

stuff.items = ['a','b','c','d']

stuff[Symbol.iterator] = stuff.items[Symbol.iterator].bind(stuff.items);

for(let n of stuff){
    console.log(n) // It doesn't happen
}
```